# align the first digit for floats C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Needing to align floats by the first digit, not by the decimal. I'm not 100% on the intricacies of setw(), so not sure if the output I'm looking for is even possible. Tried searching for an answer for a couple hours now, and nothing seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. The field width isn't accurate here, they're just placements, but they still don't give desired output regardless.

Current code:

```
cout << setw(14) << collections1 << setw(18) << collections2 << setw(15) <<
     collections3 << endl ;
```

Current output:

```
Collections1:    Collections2:    Collections3:
     11.00           111.00        111.00
     22.00           222.00        222.00
     33.00           333.00        333.00
    444.00          4444.00        444.00
    555.00          5555.00        555.00
    666.00          6666.00        666.00
```

Desired output:

```
 Collections1:    Collections2:    Collections3:
   11.00           111.00             111.00
   22.00           222.00             222.00
   33.00           333.00             333.00
   444.00          4444.00            444.00
   555.00          5555.00            555.00
   666.00          6666.00            666.00
```

Have tried aligning right, left, but nothing seems to work.

Edit 1: Believe I may have found a good enough solution.

```
cout << left << "\t" setw(14) << collections1 << setw(18) << collections2 << setw(15) << collections3 << endl ;
```

Not certain if this is poor or not, but it gets the job done for the moment.

Comment: I think it's prettier and easier to read with the decimals lined up, IMHO.

Comment: I agree completely, but unfortunately, that's not what's being asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using left function for streaming your output as below:

```
std::cout.width(6); std::cout << std::left << n << '\n';
```

Comment: Well, Collections1 calls for it to be right-justified, so while left does solve one problem, it creates another. Unless there's something I'm missing with it.

Comment: Can you post more snippet of code to understand more about issue ? or you can make test sample to check..

Comment: Think I got an answer, posted it in edit. Thanks for your input, rethought it with your using an escape sequence.

Comment: @BlackLeatherSocks: Thats good ! You can upvote if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

> Needing to align floats by the **first digit**, **not by the decimal**.

You can use `std::left`, `std::setw` and `std::setfill` as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec{{10.0233, 122.1, 1203.1},{100.03, 22.15, 3.01},{107.03, 152.1, 0.1},{6686.0,6666.00,666.00}};
    
    for(std::vector<double> tempVec: vec)
    {
        for(double elem: tempVec)
        {
            std::cout << std::left<<std::setw(8) << std::setfill(' ') << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << elem << "    ";
        }
        std::cout<< std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/gd0xsPQnBz) of the above program is :

```
10.02       122.10      1203.10     
100.03      22.15       3.01        
107.03      152.10      0.10        
6686.00     6666.00     666.00
```